# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'; python3.7 ,tensorflow 2.11.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

tried to run the following code on jupyter notebook

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
```

error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13480\2236388005.py in <module>
      1 import tensorflow
      2 
----> 3 from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
      4 from keras.layers import Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout
      5 from keras.preprocessing import image

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     19 """
     20 from keras import distribute
---> 21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py in <module>
     22 import warnings
     23 
---> 24 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     25 
     26 from keras import backend

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

I tried

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
```

as well, but that returns error saying

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

Python version: 3.7
Keras version: 2.11.0
Tensorflow version: 2.11.0

Comment: Did you name your own project `tensorflow`? Or have a package (folder with `__init__.py`) with that name inside your project?

Comment: No. I only have one ipynb file for my project and it is not named after tensorflow. Thank you

Comment: Does anything from tensorflow works? What is your OS? Because 2.11.0 is available for 3.7 but some wheels seem broken - see here https://inspector.pypi.io/project/tensorflow/2.11.0/ - see how `tensorflow-2.11.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl` and `tensorflow-2.11.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` have basically no files. Other cp37 (cpython3.7) wheels have hundreds of files (to the point of PyPI Inspector sometimes showing 502 because it can't manage it, it's a light tool)

Comment: Hi @Serafinu Dibattfoli, It seems there is an issue with installing TensorFlow because I am able to successfully import these libraries in given configurations. Could you please check and verify that you have followed all the [step by step instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) mentioned in the link to install TensorFlow. Let us if the issue still persists.